# Связь сущностей с сохранением порядка следования дочерних объектов

Tags: sql, entity-framework

Допустим моя база данных содержит таблицу `TextStrings`, где каждая сущность содержит одну текстовую строку, например:

"меня ", "привет ", "Игорь ", "зовут ", "Виталий ", "Владимир "

Также у меня есть таблица `TextDocuments`, где каждая сущность содержит связь со множеством сущностей `TextStrings`. Например я хочу создать сущность `TextDocument` которую можно собрать во фразу "привет меня зовут Игорь". Т.е. мне нужны сущности `TextString` с Id 2, 1, 4, 3 строго в таком порядке. При этом другие текстовые документы Могут использовать другие текстовые строки и комбинировать их по другому. Единственное что приходит мне на ум, это хранить строку, где Id дочерних сущностей перечисляются через запятую, т.е. `"2,1,4,3"` но получается сложно и костыльно. Как я могу правильно реализовать указанную структуру?

Comment: Если `TextStrings` не существуют сами по себе (т.е. являются частью документа и имеют на него ссылки в виде внешнего ключа), то добавить в `TextStrings` поле `index`, которое будет хранить номер строки по порядку в документе. Иначе создать таблицу связи между `TextStrings` и `TextDocuments` - `TextDocumentStrings` с полями `document_id, string_id, string_index`

Comment: @RomanKonoval Т.е. это наподобие таблицы при образовании связи "много-много", но с одним дополнительным столбцом? А при формировании модели Entity framework не "потеряет" этот столбец? Просто у меня опыта со связями типа "много-много" пока нет.

Comment: По entity-framework не подскажу, судя по быстрому поиску из коробки (как скажем в джаве с JPA) это, вроде бы, не поддерживается, может я не нашел, и что подскажут те, кто использует EF.

Comment: необходимую таблицу можно создать ручками: `public class DocumentsTexts { public int DocumentId {get;set;} public int StringId {get;set;} public int Order {get;set;} }` после чего при помощи linq запроса `_context.Set<DocumentsTexts>().Where(x=>x.DocumentId == documentId).OrderBy(x=>x.Order)` можно будет собрать строку